# Background-size: cover not clearly display on Iphone

Tags: html, css, safari

Good day! 
This line of CSS Code is working fine using the other browser. But whenever I tried to run the code using safari. The image doesn't show nicely. Some thread said explains that I must use media query for iPhone: *Example code below of Iphone Media Query*

```
 @media (max-width: @iphone-screen) {
    background-attachment: scroll;
  }
```

But that code doesn't work properly. Can anyone help me how can I fix this?
This is my Code:

```
#video {
background: url("images/sample_8.jpg");
-webkit-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-attachment:fixed;
 position: relative;
 color: #999;
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
 filter: grayscale(100%);
 }
```

Comment: try background-size: contain; for iPhone

Answer (score 0):

You can try `background-size:contain;` for iphone:

```
 @media (max-width: @iphone-screen) {
    background-size:contain;
  }
```